# Unable to send message to kafka Producer using kafka-node

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-node

I am using default server.properties/zookeeper.properties files provided by Kafka framework.

I am trying to create a simple NodeJS app which would send messages to Producer and consume them.

Below is NodeJS code.

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  kafka_topic: 'catalog',
  kafka_server: 'localhost:9092',
};
```

nodejs-producer.js

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const config = require('./config');

try {

    // set the desired timeout in options
    const options = {
        timeout: 5000,
    };
    const Producer = kafka.Producer;
    const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: config.kafka_server, requestTimeout: 5000});
    const producer = new Producer(client);
    const kafka_topic = config.kafka_topic;
    let payloads = [
        {
            topic: kafka_topic,
            messages: 'This is test message'
        }
    ];

    producer.on('ready', async function() {
        let push_status = producer.send(payloads, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());
                console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update failed');
            } else {
                console.log(data.toString());
                console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update success');
            }
        });
    });

    producer.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: connection errored');
        throw err;
    });
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

kafka version = 2.8.0
kafka-node version = 5.0.0

I am getting the error - Error: LeaderNotAvailable

How to fix this? I tried playing with different values in server.properties file like advertised.listeners but didn't get solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leader Not Available Kafka in Console Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788697/leader-not-available-kafka-in-console-producer)

Answer (score 0):

I have already [answered this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189159/1545425)

In short: **this problem happens when trying to produce messages to a topic that doesn't exist.**

You may configure your kafka installation to automatically create topic in such case: what will then happen is - in order: you will still receive the error message and the framework will create the topic. In my case i then had to re-produce the same message a second time but this was on an old version of Kafka.

EDIT:
[here a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36442306/1545425) to a post which explains how to setup your kafka configuration to automatically create kafka topics.

Comment: I have created the topic already via CLI command. 

Details of topic are as below:

-> Command: /zookeeper-shell.sh ZooKeeper -server localhost:2181  get /brokers/topics/catalog
 
-> Result:
{"partitions":{"0":[3,1],"1":[1,2],"2":[2,3]},"topic_id":"1nKW2XXXXXXmtkNQ_A","adding_replicas":{},"removing_replicas":{},"version":3}

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue while sending a message. I solved the issue by adding a partition in the payload and same partition is used in the consumer also.

[Code I have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFe0n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since I got this error in the development environment. I solved this problem by deleting the zookeeper snapshot and Kafka consumer offset.

NOTE: Don't do this on production.

```
rm -rf /tmp/zookeeper
rm -rf /tmp/kafka-logs
```